# finding all whitespace in a line

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove all the white space in my data file and replace it with one comma `,` I am currently using regex to do this.

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse_prime.py", line 12, in <module>
    newline = line.replace(whitespace,",")
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Here is my code

```
import re

token = re.compile(r'\s*')
f = open("prime_data.txt","r")
fw = open("prime_out.txt", "w+")

primelist = []

for line in f.readlines():
    findtoken = re.search(token, line)
    replacetoken = line.replace(findtoken,",")

    fw.write(newline)
```

I dont think I am searching for the regex properly. I think I am stopping once the first set of whitespace is found. How do I look through the whole line?

the data file is in this format

```
43    3    2    2    123    3
```

Comment: Why not just use: `for line in ... (): fw.write(re.sub(r'\s+', ',', line))` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `token.sub()` here, and use the correct pattern (match at least one whitespace character or more):

```
token = re.compile(r'\s+')

for line in f:
    newline = token.sub(line, ',')
    fw.write(newline)
```

I dropped the `.readlines()` call; file objects can be looped over *directly*, no need to read them into memory wholesale.

You could also just use `str.split()` here instead, no regular expressions required:

```
for line in f:
    newline = ','.join(line.split())
    fw.write(newline + '\n')
```

You were trying to call `str.replace()` which only accepts strings, but you were passing in a `re.MatchObject` value instead.

Comment: Also, `\s+` is better. Wouldn't want to replace even 'empty' matches by `,`, right?